# Keras Time Series Cross Validation

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I want to implement the cross-validation strategy below with time series data in a Keras LSTM.

[image]

Let's say I have *n* time series which I split each into *m* blocks.
Since, I will be validating after every one of the *nm* input chunks, I am not sure how this will work with [model.fit()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Model#fit) in keras. How could I set up my training to loop, say 300 times, over all *nm* data chunks, validating after training each chunk?

As a bonus: Is there a way to use Keras' early stopping with this approach?